# Elasticsearch shield set up ssl with letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Im trying to set shield (es 2.2.0) with ssl following the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ssl-tls.html#ssl-tls), the steps are:

1. Installing Node Certificates:

   a. Create a node keystore and import your CA’s certificate with Java Keytool.

   ```
   # cd CONFIG_DIR/shield
   # keytool -importcert -keystore node01.jks -file cacert.pem -alias my_ca
   ```

I get troubles already with the error:

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacert.pem (No such file or directory)
```

I don`t understand, do I have to have signed certificate from letsencrypt first and then sign it again for es shield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import your certificate authority pem file in the first step. You can download it from [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/). Replace cacert.pem with the file you download.